# Reading the values from and Writing to the XML File in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read the values from the XML file after doing some modifications and I want to write it to the same file.
**Note:- It should not read the commented values from XML**

Web.config:-

```
<add key="InputDataFileName" value="InputData.xml" />
```

Here is my code,

```
string inputxmlPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputDataFileName"];
            XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            readerSettings.IgnoreComments = true;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputxmlPath, readerSettings);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);
            var ParentNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//TestData"); //This is the root Node
            if (ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode child in ParentNode)
                {
                    string elementName = child.LocalName;
                    switch (elementName)
                    {
                        case "URL":
                            for (int i = 0; i < child.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                            {
                                XmlNode node = child.ChildNodes[i].FirstChild;
                                node.InnerText = CMEURL;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "LoadBalanceList":
                            for (int i = 0; i < child.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                            {
                                XmlNode node = child.ChildNodes[i].FirstChild;
                                node.InnerText = CMEURL;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Activity":
                            for (int i = 0; i < child.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                            {
                                XmlNode node = child.ChildNodes[i].FirstChild;
                                node.InnerText = CMEURL;
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            doc.Save(inputxmlPath); //Getting an exception here
```

**Exception: IOException was unhandled by user code**
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Desktop\Patching \source\Automation\InputData.xml' because it is being used by another process.

Getting an exception in the **Save** method
Not Sure what I did wrong, Could anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never closing the `XmlReader`, so it's still got an open file handle for reading - which means you can't write to the same file. You should put it in a `using` statement:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreComments = true };
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputXmlPath, settings))
{
    doc.Load(reader);
}
```

I'd personally use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument` though:

```
XDocument doc;
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreComments = true };
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputxmlPath, settings))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: Now It is working, But the commented line got overided after saving the file

Comment: @Vishnu: It's not at all clear what you mean. I would expect any comments to be effectively removed, because you've explicitly not read them.

Comment: thanks now I got it...could u provide me some links for how to read xml explicitly.. I'll try it out...

Comment: @Vishnu: No, I think you misunderstood me. You're creating an `XmlReaderSettings` which says "ignore comments" - so when it reads the comments, it ignores them. What did you expect that to do?

Comment: oh ok, I thought the commented values also will write to the XML file, Now I'm clear, Thanks for the time in ur busy schedule..

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispose of your reader before you try to write to the file:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputxmlPath, readerSettings))            
   doc.Load(reader);
```

Now you still have the reader open, so the reader is accessing the file, and when you call `doc.Save()` the `XmlDocument` tries to access the file at the same time.
The `using` statement takes care of disposing the reader for you, so the file isn't being used by the reader anymore when you call `Save()`. It's always a good idea to use resources with a `using` statement, instead of manually closing/disposing a resource.